# imagemagick convert pdf with text(no scan) to gibberish

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am processing pdf files with imagemagick to images but this particular file is processed to some really gibberish stuff
To simplify stuff I am doing simple

```
convert file.pdf out.jpg
```

Just an idea is that it is mix of text pdf and image pdf and this could cause troubles. Can you help?
Pages of document which are in text are converted to this gibberish, last page which is actually scan is fine
[image]

this is the link to the original
[file](https://rpvs.gov.sk/rpvs/Partner/Partner/Dokument/48652)

EDIT: I found out that also files without combination of text and scan are causing issues, actually files which contain text data, not scanned image. So the question is how to setup imagemagick to convert pdf with pure text to image without getting this output

Comment: What is your ImageMagick version and platform? Does it include Ghostscript? If so, what is the version of Ghostscript. If that is not the most current, update Ghostscript. Do you have the Ghostscript fonts install? It works fine for me with ImageMagick 6.9.10.7 Q16 with GS 9.23 on Mac OSX Sierra. I get 5 resulting pages as individual JPG files.

Comment: I have the version of ImageMagick 6.9.7-4 Q16  and ghostscript 9.22 on ubuntu 18.04.1 and if I try to update system shows me these are the latest versions. Actually when I tried to convert on my dev machine where is imagemagic 6.8.9-9 Q16 and ghostscript 9.18 all works fine

Comment: It is likely the ghostscript version. I am on 9.23. Perhaps 9.22 had a bug. Worst case, downgrade Ghostscript to a version prior to 9.22, such as 9.18 and see if that fixes it. On Linux, the date associated with the version of ImageMagick is more important than the version, because Linux typically patches without changing the version date. So check the version dates as well on your two system.

Comment: yes it was ghostscript, but actually on ubuntu 18 was problem to do downgrade standard way and also 9.21 was not working...so I manually installed 9.23 and all works well. Thanks for pointing me to try different versions

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with ghostscript 9.22,
update to 9.23 helps